# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $\lfloor e x\rfloor$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Construct a function $f(x)=\lfloor e x\rfloor$.
For each positive integer $x$, $f(x)$ will be a positive integer.
Among these integers $f(x)$, are there an infinite number of primes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is $e$ meant to be the base of natural logarithms?

Comment: I made an attempt to clarify the wording, but did not explicitly venture an assumption whether, as in @MichaelEngelhardt's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414472/are-there-infinite-numbers-of-prime-ex-for-any-positive-integers-x#comment1062767_414472), $\ln(e) = 1$.  Hopefully @‍Yinpo will clarify, although @‍2734364041's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414473) suggests it doesn't matter.

Comment: @LSpice It does matter in that one wants $e$ to be an irrational number for the result to be applied - e.g. if $e=2$ there is a problem.

Comment: I mean  is an example of an irritational number, the base of natural logarithms. Or generalized speaking, this could be random irrational number. Sorry for the ambiguity of my explanation.

Answer (score 25):

Something is known in considerably greater generality.  Let $\lVert x\rVert=\min_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|x-n|$.  For $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, define

$$\tau(\gamma) = \sup\Big\{\rho\in\mathbb{R}\colon \liminf_{n\to\infty} n^{\rho}\lVert\gamma n\rVert=0\Big\},$$

where the limit inferior is as $n\to\infty$ along the integers.  Dirichlet's approximation theorem implies that for all irrational $\gamma$, we have $\tau(\gamma)\geq 1$.  Khinchin and Roth proved that $\tau(\gamma)=1$ for almost all real numbers $\gamma$ (in the sense of Lebesgue measure), and $\tau(\gamma)=1$ for all (real) irrational algebraic integers $\gamma$.

If $\gamma>1$ and $\tau(\gamma)<\infty$, then there is an asymptotic prime number theorem that counts the primes of the form $p=\lfloor \gamma n+\beta\rfloor$, where $n\geq 1$ is an integer and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed.  A standard source for this is the paper [Prime numbers with Beatty sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1015) by Banks and Shparlinski.

Comment: *"for all irrational algebraic integers"* I'm assuming you meant "real numbers" rather than "integers" here?

Comment: @Stef No, I mean an algebraic integer (a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients) that is irrational.